# `System.NullReferenceException` em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Executando o seguinte código ele apresenta o erro `System.NullReferenceException` na chamada da função `SubString`

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>

//
//  Implementado o metodo Substring para retornar um nova area de memoria
//  com os dados formatados conforme possição informada.
//
void            SubString
            (
                char        *ls_retorno,
                char        *as_origem,
                int         an_inicio,
                int         an_quantidade
            )
{

    //
    //  Variaveis de controle.
    //
    int
    ln              =   0,
    ln_cotador      =   0;

    //
    //  Se posição inicial menor que 0 ou
    //  Se posição inicial muito exagerada...
    //
    if  (an_inicio  <   0)
    {
        an_inicio   =   0;
    }

    //
    //  Obtem os caracteres desejados
    //
    for (   
            ln      =   an_inicio;
            ln      <   an_quantidade   +   an_inicio;
            ln++
        )
    {
        ls_retorno[ln_cotador++]    =   as_origem[ln];
    }

    //
    //  Elimina todos os espacos nao ocupados.
    //
    ls_retorno[ln_cotador]      =   '\0';

    printf("Resultado Funcao: >%s<",    ls_retorno);

    //
    //  Retorna a informacao tratada.
    //
//  return  (ls_retorno);
}

int main()
{

    //
    //  Cria a palavra chave e o valor.
    //
    char
    *ls_palavrad;
    char
    *ls_valord;

    //
    //  Aloca a espaco em memoria
    //
    ls_palavrad     =   (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));         
    ls_valord       =   (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));        

    //
    //  Limpa o buffer
    //

    ls_palavrad     =   (char*) NULL;
    ls_valord       =   (char*) NULL;


    printf(">Chamada<");

    SubString(ls_palavrad,  "mensagem=Sequencial invalido", 1,  5);

    printf("Retorno: >%s<", ls_palavrad);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A título de curiosidade, você não gosta de usar espaços na hora de escrever o código?

Comment: uso somente tabs

Comment: E porque você usa quebra de linha em `if`s e outras estruturas? Você não acha que fica mais difícil de ler o código assim?

Comment: desculpa  se deixa mais difícil para compreensão assim, e questão de costume mesmo

Comment: Você aloca memória para  a variável `ls_palavrad` e logo em seguida você "limpa o buffer" dela com `(char*) NULL`. Quando você executa `SubString(ls_palavrad, ..., ...` você tenta acessar: `ls_retorno[ln_cotador++]` no que resulta o `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: mas se eu apenas criar e fazer o malloc fica com lixo, alguma dica de como passo fix isso\?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>

void SubString (char *ls_retorno,  char *as_origem,  int an_inicio, int an_quantidade  )  {
    int ln = 0, ln_cotador = 0;

    if (an_inicio < 0)
        an_inicio = 0;

    for (ln = an_inicio; ln < an_quantidade + an_inicio; ln++)
        ls_retorno[ln_cotador++] = as_origem[ln];

    ls_retorno[ln_cotador] = '\0';

    printf("Resultado Funcao: >%s<", ls_retorno);
}


int main() {
    char *ls_palavrad;
    char *ls_valord;

    ls_palavrad = (char*) malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    ls_valord = (char*) malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

    printf(">Chamada<");

    SubString(ls_palavrad, "mensagem=Sequencial invalido", 1, 5);

    printf("Retorno: >%s<", ls_palavrad);

    free(ls_palavrad);
    free(ls_valord);

    ls_palavrad = NULL;
    ls_valord = NULL;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: mas se eu apenas criar e fazer o malloc fica com lixo

Comment: Um ponteiro armazena lixo somente se for declarado sem ser inicializado com um valor correto,  ou quando for deslocado pela função `free` sem ser setado como `NULL` posteriormente.

Comment: onde isso acontece ali?

Comment: A maneira correta de se utilizar ponteiros é fazer a alocação usando ´malloc()´, como você fez no ´main()´, e DEPOIS de ter usado os ponteiros você deve usar a função ´free()´ para liberar a memória.

Se você usar malloc e depois setar os ponteiros como ´NULL´, que foi o que você fez, você não vai estar liberando a memória. Os bytes alocados por malloc continuarão na memória e você não conseguirá acessar mais aquele endereço, porque você os perdeu quando fez os ponteiros igual a ´NULL´

Comment: assim, estou fazendo isso

Comment: mesmo naquele print ali logo apos a função já imprime lixo

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta com o código, só um instante.

Comment: @LucasFernandes confere a resposta